# svn https: "ra_serf: An error occurred during SSL communication"

Tags: svn, ssl, https, tortoisesvn

I have randomly errors like these (svn and https) :
- ra_serf: An error occurred during SSL communication
- Error retrieving REPORT: An error occurred during SSL communication

with `svn update` on the repositories hosted by a private company. But these problems appear only on one station. In order to finish the update, I must use `svn cleanup` every time after this error.

Sometimes this problem appears early after the first updated files, sometimes it appears after many files or not at all (rarely). On the same Internet connection, I can update my working copy without problem with an other computer using `svn` on Linux (for example).

It suggests that I have something wrong in my settings (Windows ?, conflict with an other software?). But I have no idea where and why.
These problems appear with TortoiseSVN and with the `svn` command line too. Then it is not related to TortoiseSVN. I use the last SVN version (1.8.3) but this problem was already there with older versions like 1.7.x.

I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall TortoiseSVN but it changes nothing.

I use an updated version of Windows 7.

Comment: I'm getting this error as well now. Did you find an answer at all? I'm using a desktop and laptop and if I check in from one and try to update on the other I'm getting the error. I updated both versions of TortoiseSVN to the same versions and still no luck.

Comment: Hi, still no answer... I update my working copies by `svn cleanup && svn up` in loop. It's very annoying...

Comment: I actually found the answer to my problem. I have two VPN clients installed on my VM for different clients and they seem to conflict unless I have them both running at the same time.

Comment: Well... I never found the reason of this issue.. and we have mostly switched to git then it's no longer a problem for me...

Comment: This problem appeared after upgrading my develompent machine from Windows 10 to 11. Don't know if it is really related to the upgrade though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this issue is caused by your network driver. I had the same issue because Avast installed its own network driver which gave me bluescreen on Windows 8.

I solved this by uninstalling Avast.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with this once as well, it solved itself by deactivating my anti-virus program while I was using SVN. (In my case it was Avira).

At the time, I was told that had something to do with network ports.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. What solved it for me:

- Deactivated Norton
- Then update SVN

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem, I try to disconnect with a net adapter and it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

After failure with "Error: ra_serf: An error occurred during SSL communication "

Try to do SVN CLEANUP on the same directory and UPDATE the repository again. It works for me.

I am connected over VPN. Antivirus & Firewall everything is running but i felt it has nothing to do with them.